# Could not parse the remainder: '(object.listattribute)' from 'len(object.listattribute)'

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a list attribute

```
class myObj:

    def getlist(self):
        return self.list
```

The list is populated with objects or instanced as an empty list.

In a template I perform the following:

```
{% if len(myObj.list) > 0 %}
    <img class="status" src="{% static "images/Check.png" %}" />
{% else %}
    <img class="status" src="{% static "images/YellowWarning.png" %}" />
{% endif %}
```

I am receiving the following:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(myObj.list)' from 'len(myObj.list)'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

`len(myObj.list)` is invalid syntax in django templates.
You could use the [`length` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) instead.

```
{% if myObj.list|length > 0 %}
```

Comment: Or just `if myObj.list`, since an empty list is boolean False.